# how to understand the output of tf.nn.top_k() from tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I used tf.nn.top_k()function from tensorflow to use the model's softmax probabilities to visualize the certainty of its predictions with 5 new images and with k=5. I have an output as follows which I am not sure how to exactly interpret. Could anyone explain the output please.

```
TopKV2(values=array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]], dtype=float32), indices=array([[13,  0,  1,  2,  3],
       [13,  0,  1,  2,  3],
       [13,  0,  1,  2,  3],
       [26,  0,  1,  2,  3],
       [13,  0,  1,  2,  3]], dtype=int32))
```

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/top_k), it returns two tensors: the first with the top K value and the second with the indices of these values in the original tensor.

So for your data what I see is that the original tensor is always one-hot (i.e. has a single 1.0 entry per row and is 0 everywhere else).

Comment: I believe the first set of 5 are the probabilities for each image of and the second set are the classes it has classified for each image. But not %100 sure.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what happens.

Comment: Top in what way?  Sorted by what criteria?

Comment: By the numeric value?