# How to concat the matrix with intervals in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

My English is poor. I will try my best to clarify my question.

So, I have two matrices:

`matrix1=[[1,3],[5,7]]`

`matrix2 =[[2,4],[6,8]]`

I would like to concatenate them and sort them like the matrix below:

`matrix3=[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]`

I tried this method:

```
matrix1=[[1,3],[5,7]];  
matrix2 =[[2,4],[6,8]];

with tf.Session() as sess:
   input1=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[2,2])
   input2=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[2,2])
   output=how_to_concat(input1,input2)
   sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
   [matrix3] = sess.run([output], feed_dict={input1:matrix1, input2: matrix2})
```

I want to implement `how_to_concat` to concatenate the matrices and sort two  `(2, 2)` matrices to one `(2, 4)` matrix. I tried the code below, but it didn't work as excepted:

```
def how_to_concat(input1,input2)
    output=tf.Variable(tf.zeros((2,4)))
    output=tf.assign(output[:,::2],input1)
    output=tf.assign(output[:,1::2],input2)
    return output
```

Comment: Could you use something else than tensorflow something like Numpy, or basic python ? or take a look at this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43382288/6809926

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use basics python to do this, or Numpy libs to achieve that.
Following this answer I getting it working as you wanted : https://stackoverflow.com/a/41859635/6809926

So with tensorflow you can use [top_k](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/top_k) method, which is explained right here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/40850305/6809926.
And you will found the code below.

```
import numpy as np
matrix1=[[1,3],[5,7]]  
matrix2 =[[2,4],[6,8]]

res = []
# Basic python
for i in range(len(matrix1)):
    new_array = matrix1[i] + matrix2[i] 
    res.append(sorted(new_array))
print("Concatenate with Basic python: ", res)

# Using Numpy 
res = np.concatenate((matrix1, matrix2), axis=1)
print("Concatenate with Numpy: ", np.sort(res))

sess = tf.Session()
# Using Tensorflow
def how_to_concat(input1,input2):
    array_not_sorted = tf.concat(axis=1, values=[input1, input2])
    row_size = array_not_sorted.get_shape().as_list()[-1]
    top_k = tf.nn.top_k(-array_not_sorted, k=row_size)
    return top_k
res = how_to_concat(matrix1, matrix2)

print("Concatenate with TF: ", sess.run(-res.values))
```

Output

> Concatenate with basic python: [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]
>
> Concatenate with Numpy: [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]
>
> Concatenate with TF: [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]

Comment: Thank you for your response. Here are my questions. 【1】. I want to concat the matrix with intervals, so the matrix3 is [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]], not [ matrix1, matrix2 ], so the tf.concat maybe not useful. 【2】In my code, the `how_to_concat` contains other operations about input1 and input2. You mentioned I can use numpy. But I don't how to transfer the tf.plcaeholders to numpy arrays? Can you specify the details?

Comment: I didn't get what you mean by "concat the matrix with intervals". what's the difference between your "matrix3 is [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]" and mines ?

Comment: if tf.concat is used, the result is [matrix1,matrix2]=[[1,3,2,4],[5,7,6,8]],not the expected matrix3=[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]].

Comment: Ok thanks for the better understanding I updated my answer to make it work.